# Java screen resolution change

Tags: java, osx-snow-leopard, fullscreen

I am following a series of tutorials on game development in Java by thenewboston on Youtube. I am at the point where I can make a fullscreen window, but the resolution refuses to resize to 800x600. I have tested vc, a GraphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice object, and dm, a DisplayMode, and they don't seem to be the problem. I am running Snow Leopard.  Any ideas?

```
if(dm != null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()){
        try{
            vc.setDisplayMode(dm);
            System.out.println("Display mode set");
        }catch(Exception ex){System.out.println("Despite the vc saying it is display change supported and the DM is not null, something went wrong");}

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an exception when this code executes? If so, try printing out the error message with `ex.getMessage()` or `ex.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Similar code works on Leopard. It may help to edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: @Hunter McMillen: No, I don't get any error messages. Sorry.

Comment: @me: I stand very corrected, I got a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Invalid display mode.

Comment: @me again: WHY DOES ENTER POST?! also, DisplayMode declaration, in case something is wrong. DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(800,600,16,DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);

Comment: Check that, it's fixed. Had to change the bit depth to 32. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: @WalterCoggeshall No big deal, just make sure to always get the message from the exception in your catch blocks. Empty catch blocks can cause hours of debugging.

Comment: @WalterCoggeshall Can you answer your own question and mark it as Resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your Core.java (or GameClient.java) class. The issue may be that you are not passing the required DM[] args to your ScreenManager.java class.

```
private static final DisplayMode modes[] = { //common monitor DMs 
    new DisplayMode(1366,768,32, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN), //1366x768px w/32-bit depth
    new DisplayMode(1366,768,24, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN), //    '      w/24-bit depth
    new DisplayMode(1366,768,16, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN), //    '      w/16-bit depth     
    new DisplayMode(800,600,32, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN),  //800x600px  w/32-bit depth
    new DisplayMode(800,600,24, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN),  //    '      w/24-bit depth
    new DisplayMode(800,600,16, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN),  //    '      w/16-bit depth 
    new DisplayMode(640,480,32, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN),  //640x480px  w/32-bit depth
    new DisplayMode(640,480,24, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN),  //    '      w/24-bit depth
    new DisplayMode(640,480,16, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN),  //    '      w/16-bit depth
};
```

I'm assuming that the error is with your public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm) method. In that case, the full syntax for this method is:

```
/*****************************************************************************
 * @description: Creates window for program to run in, using appropriate DM
 * @param DisplayMode dm 
 */
    public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setUndecorated(true); //no titlebars/scroll bars etc.
        f.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        f.setResizable(false); //user cannot resize window
        vc.setFullScreenWindow(f);

        if(dm!=null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()){ //if DM is changeable
            try {
                vc.setDisplayMode(dm);
            } catch (Exception e){/*Catch 'em all*/}
        }
        f.createBufferStrategy(2); //set # of screen buffers to 2
    }//setFullScreen()
```

Noticed this was a mild necro-post after posting. Aaahh...